# StaleElementReferenceException in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the Sunshine List website (http://www.sunshinelist.ca/) using the Selenium package but I get the following error mentioned  below. From several other related posts I understand that I need to use the WebDriverWait to explicitly ask the driver to wait/refresh but I am unable to identify where and how I should call the function.

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaCn2.jpg)

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference
>   of (tr class="even") stale: either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the
>   page has been refreshed

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ffx_bin = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Users\BhagatM\AppData\Local\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
ffx_caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
ffx_caps['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=ffx_caps,firefox_binary=ffx_bin)
driver.get("http://www.sunshinelist.ca/")
driver.maximize_window()

tablewotags1=[]

while True:
    divs = driver.find_element_by_id('datatable-disclosures')
    divs1=divs.find_elements_by_tag_name('tbody')

    for d1 in divs1:
        div2=d1.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
        for d2 in div2:
            tablewotags1.append(d2.text)

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next →').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

year1=tablewotags1[0::10]
name1=tablewotags1[3::10]
position1=tablewotags1[4::10]
employer1=tablewotags1[1::10]  


df1=pd.DataFrame({'Year':year1,'Name':name1,'Position':position1,'Employer':employer1})
df1.to_csv('Sunshine List-1.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each click on the "Next" button -- you should find that button and click on it.

Or do something like this:

```
max_attemps = 10

while True:

    next = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".next>a")

    if next is not None:

        break

    else:

        time.sleep(0.5)
        max_attemps -= 1

    if max_attemps == 0:

        self.fail("Cannot find element.")
```

And after this code does click action.

PS: Also try to add just `time.sleep(x)` after fiding element and then do click action.

Comment: the code I have provided is my complete code. Could you please indicate where I should include the code you provided?

Comment: I tried simply adding time.sleep(0.5) before line "divs = driver.find_element_by_id('datatable-disclosures')", but it didn't work.

Comment: @MazahirBhagat, you have a problem with "Next" link? Where are you have a problem?

Comment: The code is able to click on the next button. I have attached a screenshot of the error I am receiving for you reference.

Comment: @MazahirBhagat, add time.sleep(x) after finding tr tag. I don't know how much x should be, try on.

Comment: @MazahirBhagat, how is going? Are you fixed the problem?

Comment: I used your approach of using time.sleep(x). Even though I feel its a slightly crude approach, but I have got the code doing it's job!

Comment: @MazahirBhagat, sounds good. Also, you can use implicit and explicit waits for your problem.

Comment: could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3):

If your problem is to click the **"Next"** button, you can do that with the xpath:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/pathTo/geckodriver')
driver.get("http://www.sunshinelist.ca/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
el=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ul[@class='pagination']/li[@class='next']/a[@href='#' and text()='Next → ']")))
el.click()
```

Comment: The code is able to click on the next button but the code randomly stops and throws the above mentioned error.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the error I am receiving, for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below.
When the element is no longer attached to the DOM and the StaleElementReferenceException is invoked, search for the element again to reference the element.

Please do note I checked with Chrome:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="datatable-disclosures_wrapper"] li[class="next"]>a').click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[id="datatable-disclosures_wrapper"] li[class="next"]>a').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Comment: I am new to Python. The code I have provided is my complete code. Could you please indicate where I should include the code you have provided? Should it replace the 'try' section of my while loop?

Comment: Yes. replace the code of the try section and let me know if it works. I tried it worked on my system

Comment: Put a print statement in the except StaleElementReferenceException block and see if the code executes, this is to ensure at least the right exception is invoked. It should.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>Stale Exceptions can be handled using **StaleElementReferenceException** to continue to execute the for loop. When you try to get the element by any find_element method in a for loop.    

from selenium.common import exceptions  

and customize your code of for loop as:  

for loop starts:  
   try:  
        driver.find_elements_by_id("data")  //method to find element
        //your code 
   except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException:  
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

When you raise the `StaleElementException` that means that somthing changed in the site, but not in the list you have. So the trick is to refresh that list every time, inside the loop like this:

```
while True:
    driver.implicitly_wait(4)
    for d1 in driver.find_element_by_id('datatable-disclosures').find_element_by_tag_name('tbody').find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
            tablewotags1.append(d1.text)

    try:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="datatable-disclosures_wrapper"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[7]/a').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Don\'t be so cryptic about error messages, they are good\n
              ...Script broke clicking next') #jk aside put some info there
        break
```

Hope this help you, cheers.

Edit:
So I went to the said website, the layout is pretty straight forward, but the structure repeats itself like four times. So when you go about crawling the site like that something is bound to change.

So I’ve edited the code to only scrap one `tbody` tree. This tree comes from the first `datatable-disclousure`. And added some waits.

Comment: Its still giving me the same error. I have attached a screenshot of the error I am receiving, for your reference

Comment: I have used the time.sleep(x) function. Is it different from the implicit wait function you have used?

Comment: @MazahirBhagat As far as I understand, implicitly_wait(n), will wait up to that time for content to load and is set for the WebDriver lifespan - as per documentation "An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available", [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)-. As for time.sleep(n), will always wait the full n you gave it and is line dependent.